# Mapping a grid but having each node delay in css animation reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm having trouble with some css animation and I have an idea why it isnt working, but I'm not sure how to overcome it. This is done in ReactJs.

I render a grid, lets say 5, 5.

I then proceed to display the grid with a function like so:

```
  DisplayNodes = () => {
    const {grid} = this.state; // get the node array from state
    return (
      <div id="grid">
        {grid.map((rowMap, rIndex) => {
          return (
            <div class="row">
              {rowMap.map((node,nIndex) => {
                return (
                  <Node/>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

which will generate a grid that is 5 x 5.

Within the `Node` object I have a className of `node`. Some nodes are unique and have a different className with a different styling.

```
.node {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border:1px solid gray;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: black;
  transition: background-color 500ms linear;
}
```

The desired effect I wanted would be that each node would turn into its background-color of black over 500ms, one at a time. Giving it a good fade in pattern effect. The result I get is they all turn black over 500ms at the same time.

I believe this is because during the mapping it is calculated beforehand then rendered all at once complete. Not totally sure how to delay this.

I tried adding a `setTimeout` function within the map, but then in attempting to delay other node's they ended up being drawn in the incorrect location of the gird.

Comment: You are talking about each node would turn, one at a time. But how do you define the interval of two animations? I think it's impossible to delay the nodes render process, so you have to do it with some more logic code.

Comment: @Jarvan correct, this is what I'm trying to achieve. Hence my dilemma. I'm having a hard time wrapping my brain about how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do it in another way.

Instead of delaying them one by one, you could calculate the delay time from the beginning.

For example, I assume you want each takes 500ms to turn into another color, then next node start to turn and use another 500ms, then for the first node it should delay 0ms time, but for the second node it should delay 500*1 ms time, for the third should be 500*2 ms, etc.

Therefore, the mapping code should pass the index of node into node itself:

```
 DisplayNodes = () => {
    const {grid} = this.state; // get the node array from state
    return (
      <div id="grid">
        {grid.map((rowMap, rIndex) => {
          return (
            <div class="row">
              {rowMap.map((node,nIndex) => {
                return (
                  <Node index={nIndex}/>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

In the node render function, you should set a proper transition-delay CSS to it.

```
Node =(index)=>{
  const delay = index*500 + "ms";
  return <div style={{transitionDelay:delay }}>...<div>;
}
```

Then they should look animate one by one.